# Django - How to make datepicker submit form on change

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, datepicker

So I have this jQuery datepicker in my html, as shown below:

```
<form id="form" method="get" action=".">
    ...
    <input class="form-control" type="text" value="{{ range }}" name="range"
    placeholder="Date range" id="daterange"><b class="caret"></b></input>
</form>
```

And this javascript function that makes the datepicker:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#daterange").daterangepicker({
    ranges: {
     "Today": [new Date(), new Date()],
     "Yesterday": [moment().subtract("days", 1), moment().subtract("days", 1)],
     "Last Week": [moment().subtract("days", 6), new Date()],
     "Last 30 Days": [moment().subtract("days", 29), new Date()],
     "This Month": [moment().startOf("month"), moment().endOf("month")],
     "Last Month": [moment().subtract("month", 1).startOf("month"), moment().subtract("month", 1).endOf("month")],
     "Max": [moment("Jan 1, 2014"), new Date()],
    },
    opens: "right",
    onSelect: function(date, instance) {
      alert('test');
    },
    format: "YYYY-MM-DD",
    startDate: new Date(),
    endDate: new Date(),
    },
    function(start, end) {
     $("#daterange span").html(start.format("MMM D, YYYY") + " - " + end.format("MMM D, YYYY"));
    }
   );
  });
```

How would I submit the form automatically when the datepicker value is changed?

BTW: I have tried onchange="" and onSelect: function {}, and both do not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

form.html

```
<form id="form_id" method="get" action=".">
...
<input class="form-control" type="text" value="{{ range }}" name="range"
placeholder="Date range" id="daterange"><b class="caret"></b></input>
</form>
```

Check this it should work,

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
 $("#daterange").daterangepicker({
  ranges: {},
  opens: "right",
  onSelect: function() {},//remove this one
  function(start, end) {},
  onChange: function(){ $("#form_id").submit();} //add this line
 });
```

Comment: If I add this to my daterangepicker, it just stops working: the datepicker doesn't even show up anymore.

Answer (score -1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     alert();
 $("#daterange").daterangepicker({
  ranges: {},enter code here
  opens: "right",
  onSelect: function() {},//remove this one
  function(start, end) {},
  onChange: function(){ $("#form_id").submit();} //add this line
 });
  });//Add this to work this by RUMIT
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged at SO. Please, explain what you think was wrong and how you fix it.

Comment: in previous code last line are missing , which occurs java script stop showing calendar. Function was not closed properly.

Comment: Please, edit your answer, so that it comes clear from the answer itself, what the problem was and what the solution shall be.

Comment: And, by the way, how is you answer different from @hari's one above? Does it bring any additional value?